# geometry developments during the Islamic Golden Age (7-13 century)

Tags: geometry, reference-request, math-history

Can anybody refer me to publications on geometry during the Islamic Golden Age?

My interest is especially on Arab geometry an non-Euclidean geometry.

But searching for sources was a saddening experience:

I looked in Bonola's "Non Euclidean geometry " (almost 3 pages)

Bonola mentions:

- Al-Niziri ($ 9^{th}$ century ) - - unknown in wikipedia
- Nasir Eddin (1201-1274 )  - - unknown in wikipedia

I looked in Greenberg's "non euclidean geometry " ($ 3^{dr} $  edition) (just a number of unconnected references)

Greenberg mentions:

- Nasir Eddin al-Tusi (1201-1274 ) (under Wallis) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasir_al-Din_al-Tusi (?)
- Omar Khayyam (poet) (under Saccheri) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omar_Khayy%C3%A1m (
- ibn -al Haytham ($11^{th}$ century ?) (under Lambert and Taurinus)

All a bit low on content.

Is there  a publication that can tell me more?

Answer (score 4):

Also have a look at some of the publications in English by Jan Hoogendijk: [here](http://www.jphogendijk.nl/publ.html).

Answer (score 3):

here is one. episodes in the mathematics of the medieval islam by j. l. berggeren published by springer. isbn:0-387-40605-0

Answer (score 1):

J. L. Berggren wrote (or edited) the section on Mathematics in Medieval Islam (p. 515 - 675) in [The Mathematics of Egypt, Mesopotamia, China, India, and Islam. A Sourcebook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691114854).

[Roshdi Rashed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roshdi_Rashed) has written many books and papers on Arab science, including mathematics. Most are in French, but several have been translated to English.